# Espresso test not asserting when launching activity twice

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am running an instrumentation test to check if a dialog is shown when setting specific parameters on intent

```
@Test
public void shouldShowNotificationContentWhenActivityIsDestroyed() {
    final String NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "Título";
    final String NOTIFICATION_CONTENT = "Texto";

    Intent intent = buildNotificationIntent(NOTIFICATION_TITLE, NOTIFICATION_CONTENT);

    activityRule.launchActivity(intent);

    onView(withId(R.id.notification_title)).check(matches(allOf(withText(NOTIFICATION_TITLE), isDisplayed())));
    onView(withId(R.id.notification_content)).check(matches(allOf(withText(NOTIFICATION_CONTENT), isDisplayed())));
}

@NonNull
private Intent buildNotificationIntent(String NOTIFICATION_TITLE, String NOTIFICATION_CONTENT) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationsUtils.NOTIFICATION_TITLE_PARAMETER, NOTIFICATION_TITLE);
    intent.putExtra(NotificationsUtils.NOTIFICATION_TEXT_PARAMETER, NOTIFICATION_CONTENT);
    return intent;
}
```

It works pretty fine. Now, I want to check if the dialog is displayed when the intent is passed when the activity is already open.

```
@Test
public void shouldShowNotificationContentOnRunningActivity() {
    final String NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "Título";
    final String NOTIFICATION_CONTENT = "Texto";

    activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());

    Intent intent = buildNotificationIntent(NOTIFICATION_TITLE, NOTIFICATION_CONTENT);

    activityRule.launchActivity(intent);

    onView(withId(R.id.notification_title)).check(matches(allOf(withText(NOTIFICATION_TITLE), isDisplayed())));
    onView(withId(R.id.notification_content)).check(matches(allOf(withText(NOTIFICATION_CONTENT), isDisplayed())));
}
```

Here I launch the activity without parameters on intent, and then relaunch it with intent parameters. I see on the emulator the activity behaves as expected; however the test neither passes nor fails. I have tried adding a delay after the second launch, but it does not work. I have also disabled animations on developer options, as suggested on Espresso documentation.

How can I get the assertions to be called, so the test finishes successfully?

Comment: take out the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. and see what happens